# Openshift: Cannot find rack-1.5.2 in any of sources

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, openshift, gemfile

I want to run a small test Sinatra application. Here is the error message:

```
Could not find rack-1.5.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I have verified that the rack 1.5.2 gem is installed in my environment.

Here is the `Gemfile.lock`

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    rack (1.5.2)
    sass (3.1.20)
    sequel (4.10.0)
    sinatra (1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    slim (2.0.2)
      temple (~> 0.6.6)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    sqlite3 (1.3.6)
    temple (0.6.7)
    tilt (2.0.1)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  rack
  sass (= 3.1.20)
  sequel
  sinatra
  slim (= 2.0.2)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.6)
```

I would appreciate any help on how to proceed.

Comment: Reinstall the the gems via `bundle install --binstubs --path vendor` and then start the application using `bundle exec ruby my_sinatra_app.rb` or `bin/rackup config.ru` (whichever one you're using) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you getting this error when you do a git push to openshift?